# Why do the staff follow Slowik’s plan knowingly?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-menu

In the movie, The Menu, the celebrity chef Slowik

> kills all of his guests during an extravagant meal on a remote island.

All of Slowik's staff, there are a dozen of them, knowingly follow Slowik's plan to cook,

> commit suicide and murder.

As a celebrity chef, Slowik no doubt has ultimate respect from his staff; but to the extent of knowingly

> commiting suicide and murdering people,

why would his staff do it without questioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For the same reason a cult does it.

They are completely indoctrinated.
They are working from 6:00 am to 2:00. Let it sink. They are sleeping 4 hours a day. And apparently, at least 6 days a week (and that was Slovik, for all we know the team don't even have the Sunday off) . That's worse than 18th century slaves.
Yet they don't even think about (figuratively) burning out.

So mix together sleep deprivation, probably some kind of performance drug to allow them to physically survive it (but natural and local, let's not be hypocritical by using chemical drug), lack on individuality (they all sleep in the same room, without any indication of *living*), strong leadership and will to please, and you get mesmerized people who do what you want them to do after a few month of it (and people who won't do it get culled away, through either kind of termination).

Answer (score 4):

The movie is a satire and the characters are mostly stereotypes, so nothing is to be taken too literaly.

Slowik's plan is to punish the elite class that makes fine-dining devoid of the joy of eating real food and exploits the workers who create it. He's also going down as he lost his passion for cooking.

Not only is the crew loyal to him, it seems each one of them has their own reasons to follow along. For example, sous-chef Jeremy is not and never will be as talented as Slowik, so he would rather die than continue pursuing something he will never achieve.

Another member from the crew (Katherine) grew tired of fending off sexual advances from her boss, which also made her life miserable for a few months, so the whole idea of the dinner was actually hers.